# Creating JSP templates (views) dynamically from Database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing an application using Java and Spring MVC. As usual, stored one JSP file in /WEB-INF/view/ folder which is working as the View for all the requests.

Normally we have this JSP hard-coded that also has some codes to process the Model (tags and EL). Things are working fine till this point.

Now instead of hard-coding the JSP, I want to populate this JSP file dynamically from the database. So the user can upload and select different templates/themes/layouts to display his pages.

Here is the code to explain what I am trying to do (I know this is not the way but for illustration purpose only).

**/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="com.example.domain.Template" %>
<%@ page import="com.example.dao.TemplateStore" %>

<!-- Following code is supposed to return complete JSP template from the database as uploaded by the user. -->

<%= TemplateStore.getUserTemplate("userTemplate") %>
```

I searched web for this topic but could not find anything.

Any help on how to accomplish this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

IMPORTANT: I have asked this question a few days ago but marked as "off-the-topic" by some members. I am yet to understand how this question is off-the-topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026092/creating-content-of-jsp-views-in-web-inf-views-dynamically-from-the-database.

Comment: It is off-topic because you are not asking a concrete question ("I was trying to do this but found that error") but a general one ("I want to do this"), without code to explain what have you done up to now. Given that writting a file to disk is hardly a new thing, you should describe better which is the issue that you are having.

Comment: And anyway writting JSP code seems the wrong approach; an MVC approach (browser calls to servlet that redirects to a JSP that draws the answer) coupled with CSS is a more standard solution.

Comment: @SJuan76 - Thanks. I cannot write to the file system since I am using GAE and it does not allow it. 
Yes, I am using MVC approach but I want the view i.e. the JSP view itself to be generated dynamically from the Database.

Comment: I don't know JSP, but as a general templating thought, why not store the different parts as different partial templates, and then code the templates to correctly assemble the partials based on some string value that you can store in the DB?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Thanks. In that approach also, question remains the same - How to add codes of template fractions to create the composite JSP view? I have explored possibilities with Apache Tiles but it is taking me again to the static template fragments.

Comment: If your JSP is so complicated, maybe you want to skip it and go directly through a Servlet. Also, your approach is not very effective (every time you create/modify a JSP it is compiled by the container, it only affects the first request after modification but with your approach you will have that hit every time).

Comment: Are you forced to use JSP in this case? I have some similar experience using freemarker, and it is pretty straight-forward... as long as your customers don't require an on-site editor.

Answer (score 3):

If view templates are to be dynamically fetched from a database, you shouldn't think of JSP. JSPs are compiled into servlet classes and there's little support for doing that other than the standard way (static files somewhere under your webapp root).

Therefore, just consider switching the view technology (at least for the dynamic part) to some general-purpose templating library like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/). This comes with a security bonus, since there's less one can break from within such a template than from within JSP code.

You could even support multiple view technologies (perhaps anything that Spring MVC supports out-of-the-box, except for JSP) and allow your users to choose the type of template when uploading.

Then you can write a custom view resolver which would delegate to the appropriate standard resolver (Velocity, Freemarker, XSLT, whatever...) with the user-selected template.

However, if JSP is a hard requirement, I guess one ugly workaround for JSP (which should work in any servlet container) could be to fetch content from the DB and create an actual file (like `WEB-INF/templates/${primarky-key}.jsp`) under your exploded webapp root, then `RequestDispatcher.forward()` to it.

Comment: Thanks. Explored Freemarker a bit and I guess the interface TemplateLoader could help me. Though I am still curious to learn if this is possible in JSP via any means.

Comment: I edited the answer with something I think could work (although I would strongly recommend against, if you are able to choose).

Comment: I am going to deploy the app on Google App Engine which doesn't allow writing in the file system.

Comment: Then... forget about JSP if you can or try to experiment with @user2310289's answer or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You might or might not be able to do this with JSP, but you can certainly compile Java code in memory and then call it.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm

Of course going from JSP to Servlet would just be another step.